# Complex FormData in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, fetch

What I need to do: 
- `POST form-data` in `react-native` using `fetch API` request.

The formdata is given in follow format. It includes simple string, complex object, simple array, and complex array and file in single API call.

Do note that this is an api provided by third party vendor and i cannot change it. No, it won't accept `application/json` format.

**Note:** Pure `react-native app`. EXPO not supported.**.

[image]

I have data as follow. How can i serialize this data into formdata compatible?

```
let data = {
    string: "1",
    object: {
        a: 3,
        b: {
            c: 5
        }
    },
    array: [1,2,3],
    arrayComplex: [{id: 2, value: 2}, {id:3, value:3}],
    file: {
        name: 'Image.jpg',
        type: 'image/jpeg',
        uri: filePath,
    }
}
```

Comment: just to be clear, you need to create a `post` request towards third party API, sending the data given in the example?

Comment: @niklaz yup thats correct

Answer (score 0):

FormData supports simple key/value pair, it doesn't support nested data as objects from the values, so you should convert your JSON parts to strings:

```
let data = {
    string: "1",
    object: {
        a: 3,
        b: {
            c: 5
        }
    },
    array: [1,2,3],
    arrayComplex: [{id: 2, value: 2}, {id:3, value:3}],
    file: {
        name: 'Image.jpg',
        type: 'image/jpeg',
        uri: filePath,
    }
}
i.e.:
let FormDataReq = new FormData();

FormDataReq.append('arrayComplex', JSON.stringify(data.arrayComplex));
```

And then send your FormData as part of request's `body`:

```
fetch('https://url-to-api-endpoint.com', {
  method: 'POST',
  body: FormDataReq,
}).then((response) => response.json())
.then((result) => {
  console.log('Success:', result);
})
.catch((error) => {
  console.error('Error:', error);
});
```